# tinyMCE tries to load plugins from incorrect url in chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, webkit, tinymce

When I tried to load tinyMCE 4 in my website then it all works fine and dandy in Firefox, but in Chrome and Safari it doesn't work, because it can't load any of its plugins. I get this error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <            /plugins/spellchecker/plugin.js:1
```

The URL its trying to get the plugin from is `http://cake3.dev/admin/pages/display//plugins/spellchecker/plugin.js` while instead it should load the plugins from `http://cake3.dev/content/js/bower_components/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/plugin.js` which is what FF does.

So it seems that webkit doesn't get that it should use the path as a path relative to the location of tinymce.js. Is there a way I can make that explicit to webkit?

Comment: I don't get the problem if I use the cdn, but that is not my preferred option.

Comment: have you specified in document_base_url in tinymce config ?